# Is the angle on on Cartesian coordinate system between dots of all complex roots of polynomial with real coefficients the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polynomials, roots, cyclotomic-polynomials

So far I realized that any polynomial with complex roots has the even number of complex roots.Because for every  $(x-(a-b*i))$  there is  $(x-(a+b*i)) $  in order for coefficiants to be real.That means that odd degree polynomials have at least one real root.

Because of symmetry of complex numbers roots e.g. $a-b*i$ and $a+b*i$ the angle between them is the same regarding $ x$ axis.

But is it the same for other roots.
Here is example of polynomial: $x^4 + 3x +21$

Here is graph,but I am not sure are all angles the same,at least I dont see a geometric reason for that.
[complex roots on coordinate system for x^4 + 3x +21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC3i7.png)

And why are all complex roots on circle with semidiameter 1 on the same distance?
[x^10 -1 complex roots on coordinate system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avqwp.png)

Comment: What happens if I have two polynomials $f$ and $g$ whose roots have, say, angle $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively, to the $x$-axis and take the product $fg$?

Comment: As for the roots of unity, well, they're all given by $e^{\frac{2k}{10} \pi i}$ ($k = 0, \ldots, 9$) in your case (replace 10 by $n$ for the roots of $x^n - 1$). Also this example disproves your first question, no? These points do not share a common angle relative to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Regarding first comment,i dont have the slightest clue.I am not that good in Math,have basic high school knowladge of polynomials and am not sure how we can find roots of polynomials if we know their angles.

Comment: The only thing you need to know is that the roots of $fg$ are the roots of $f$ and the roots of $g$, combined. Thus, if $\alpha \neq \beta$, $fg$ will have roots with mismatched angles, which allows you to construct lots of counterexamples (just by considering polynomials of degree 2, for instance, for which you probably know how to compute the roots explicitly via the $abc$- or the $p$-$q$-formula).

Comment: I am resarching question that seems related to your hint:"Let P
 and Q
 be polynomials of degree 2
 and 3
 respectively. If we know the roots of both P
 and Q
, is there an easier way of finding the roots of the product PQ
? Do we really have to multiply them to get a degree 5
 polynomial and look for roots?"     I am not even sure what it means to have polynomial of degree 3 or 2.

Comment: An exponent of degree $n$ is a one of the form $a_n x^n + a_{n - 1} x^{n - 1} + \ldots + a_1 x + a_0$ where the $a_i$'s are just some numbers (real, or perhaps complex), called _coefficients_, and $a_n \neq 0$. $x^2 + 2x - 7$ is a polynomial of degree 2 since the highest power of $x$ to appear is $x^2$. $x^3 - 1/2 x^2$ is one of degree 3. $x^{129828} - 1$ is one of degree 129828. But unless you have some basic background about polynomials it will be difficult to justify the answers to your questions.

Comment: Oh my big mistake.English is my second language and I misunderstood degree for angle.Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: I tought polynomial with angle 3,and was like what is that supposed to mean,i tought that it may be related to triginometry.Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z$ be a complex number

I'll start from the basics. $Z$ can be expressed in the form of $x+iy$.
$$Z=x+iy$$
This can be plotted in 2 dimensional Argand plane,in which y axis is imaginary while x axis is real.

[image]

Here $x=a,y=b$. Notice that we can also say
$$a=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cosθ$$ and $$b=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sinθ$$.
Hence $$Z=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\cosθ+i\sinθ)$$
The above formula is called "Euler's formula", named after Leonhard Euler.

$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is known as modulus of $Z$ and also written in the form $|Z|$.
$θ$=Amplitude, the clockwise angle from x axis to $a+bi$

Using Taylor series, it can be proven that
$$(\cosθ+i\sinθ)=e^{iθ}$$ I will link the proof below.

So $$Z=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{iθ}=|Z|e^{iθ}$$
Also if you take $θ=π$, you get
$$e^{iπ}=\cos(π)+i\sin(π)=-1$$
This is a famous equation regarding Euler's identity

For your first doubt, regarding
$$x^4+3x+21=0$$
You might notice that the coefficient of $x^3=0$.

Formula for sum of roots in a polynomial= $\frac{-b}{a}$. Here $a$=coefficient of $x^4$,$b$=coefficient of $x^3$.
Here sum of roots $=0$.
Let them the roots be $α_1,α_2,α_3,α_4$.
$$α_1+α_2+α_3+α_4=0$$
You have stated yourself that complex roots occur in pairs. Let's assume $α_1,α_2$ and $α_3,α_4$ are pairs.
Hence $α_1+α_2=0$ and $α_3+α_4=0$. So $α_2$ is mirror image of $α_1$ w.r.t $x$ axis. Same is the case for $α_3,α_4$. Hence it appears symmetric in the Argand plane.

For your second doubt,let
$$Z^n=1 $$
Thus this polynomial must have n number of roots of unity.(A principle of algebra)

$$Z= (1)^\frac{1}{n}$$

Here $|Z|=1$. This is why, it creates an unit circle. ( Eqn for circle is $x^2 + y^2 = 1$)

But $(1)^\frac{1}{n}$ can be rewritten as ${((-1)^{2k})}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ because $(-1)^{2k} , k=0,1,2,...,k∈${$0,R^+$}$ $ is always 1.

Now we substitute the value of -1 from earlier, to get

$$Z={((e^{iπ})^{2k})}^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Or
$$Z=e^{\frac{2kπi}{n}}$$

Hence,as you learnt earlier, $\frac{2kπ}{n}$ will be the amplitude of our root.

But $k$ can have multiple values, starting from $0$. But we know, there must be $n$ roots. Thus, k will have values from $0$ to $(n-1)$. So the roots will be:-

$$e^0,e^{\frac{2π}{n}},e^{\frac{4π}{n}},...e^{\frac{2(n-1)π}{n}}$$

These represents all the possible roots of $n$. For $n=10$, which is given in the Wikipedia example, there exists 10 such roots with all these different angles, which lie on the unit circle. If connected, these points form a regular polygon of n sides.

[Proof of $(\sinθ+i\cosθ)=e^{iθ}$](https://www.ctralie.com/Teaching/Euler/#:%7E:text=Proving%20it%20via%20Taylor%20Series%20expansion,-Recall%20from%20my&text=You%20should%20now%20recognize%20a)

Answer (score 0):

I see different angles in your figure.

Here is a case where the difference is more obvious:
the roots of $x^4 - 2 x^3 + 3 x^2 - 2 x + 2$ plotted on the complex plane.

[image]

If you only meant is the angle the same within each conjugate pair of roots, but can be a different angle for another pair of roots, then of course the answer is yes for the reason you have already given.

If you want to know how I came by this example, I decided what I wanted my four roots to be (remembering that I needed the ones in the lower plane to be mirror images of the ones in the upper plane), then I wrote out the polynomial in the form $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$ and multiplied it out.
(Technically, I took the lazy way out and had Wolfram Alpha multiply it for me, as well as generate the graph of the roots.)