In formula $x_k=\cos(2k \pi/n) +i \sin(2k \pi/n)$ why does $k$ goes from $0$ to $n-1$?
Formula is for finding roots of unity.
I know to prove that it will work for any k,but can't see in the formula why k needs to be from $0...n-1$.
Obviously equation $x^n -1=0$ has $n$ roots,but why are k's those values.
Using Moivre's formulas:${xk}^n=(cos(2k*pi/n) + isin(2kpi/n)^n=cos(2k*pi) + isin(2k*pi)=1$

Here is a MathJax tutorial.  Note that $\cos(0 \pi/n)=\cos(2n \pi/n)$ and likewise for $\sin$

what will happen if $k=n+1$, $2pi*const$ will always give the same result anyway

There are $n$ roots but as $\cos a + i\sin a$ can be written as $\cos(a + 2m\pi) + i\sin(a+2m\pi)$ there are an infinite number of ways to write these roots.   Writing the roots as $\cos(\frac {k}n\cdot 2\pi)+i\sin (\frac kn\cdot 2\pi)$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ are all the roots but they are written an infinite number of times.  Picking $k\in {0,1,2, ...,n -1}$ is a convenient and representative way of writing them only once but it's not the only way.  We COULD pick $k\in{1, n+2, 2n+3, 3n+4,...., (n-1)n+n}$ if we wanted to. But it's convenient to have ... to be cont....

I tought so,It does make sense.Thank you!

... the "basic" root be for $k=1$ and then have the rest just be raising them all to powers.

"what will happen if k=n+1, 2pi∗const will always give the same result anyway" that'd be fine... but unconventional... and harder .... and not as clear.... and elves will put thistles in your bed.... but otherwise it is just fine.

I explained it in your question lmao. Here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4889534/1188598.
